# Contar letras de uma string sem o espaço (ou outro caractere)

Tags: python, string

Gostaria de saber como contar o número de caracteres, mas sem espaço.

Tentei tirar espaços com strip, mas não resolveu:

```
texto='123 456 78'
qtdletras = len(texto.strip())
print(qtdletras)
```

Resultado: 10, eu esperava 8

Comment: Converti seu problema em um [mcve], fica de referência para próximas postagens.

Comment: Vale lembrar que as soluções abaixo consideram que o texto vai ter apenas letras/números e espaços. Se quiser uma solução mais genérica (textos com sinais de pontuação, etc), teria que fazer algo assim: https://ideone.com/i86BHQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método strip apenas remove os espaços no começo e fim da string.

Neste caso, o ideal é usar o método replace, que irá substituir todos os espaços por um caractere escolhido (ou nenhum caractere neste caso), da seguinte forma.

```
ncarac= len(texto.replace(" ","")) # troca espaços por "nada"
print(ncarac)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo pelo método que você sugeriu.

Answer (score 1):

temos outra opção que seria:

```
# obtem tamanho do texto e subtrai contagem de espaços
textoTam = len(texto) - texto.count(" ")
print(textoTam)
```

Answer (score -3):

*Uma forma de resolver*

```
texto = '123 456 78'
texto_sem_espacos = texto.replace(' ', '')
qtdletras = len(texto_sem_espacos)
print(qtdletras)
```